# Sample dataframe maintaining multiple frequency distributions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random, sample

I have an example [`pandas dataframe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), `df`, below:

`{'column_a': {0: 'b',   1: 'b',  2: 'a',  3: 'b',  4: 'd',  5: 'a',  6: 'b',  7: 'b',  8: 'c',  9: 'a',  10: 'a',  11: 'a',  12: 'a',  13: 'c',  14: 'c',  15: 'c',  16: 'b',  17: 'a',  18: 'a',  19: 'b',  20: 'd',  21: 'c',  22: 'a',  23: 'b',  24: 'c',  25: 'c',  26: 'c',  27: 'e',  28: 'e',  29: 'e',  30: 'e',  31: 'c',  32: 'e',  33: 'e',  34: 'd',  35: 'e',  36: 'd',  37: 'e',  38: 'd',  39: 'b',  40: 'd',  41: 'c',  42: 'b',  43: 'd',  44: 'c',  45: 'e',  46: 'd',  47: 'c',  48: 'e',  49: 'b',  50: 'c'}, 'column_b': {0: 'c',  1: 'b',  2: 'b',  3: 'd',  4: 'b',  5: 'a',  6: 'd',  7: 'c',  8: 'c',  9: 'd',  10: 'a',  11: 'a',  12: 'b',  13: 'a',  14: 'c',  15: 'd',  16: 'd',  17: 'c',  18: 'b',  19: 'd',  20: 'a',  21: 'a',  22: 'd',  23: 'b',  24: 'a',  25: 'c',  26: 'e',  27: 'd',  28: 'b',  29: 'c',  30: 'd',  31: 'b',  32: 'e',  33: 'b',  34: 'b',  35: 'c',  36: 'b',  37: 'b',  38: 'd',  39: 'c',  40: 'b',  41: 'a',  42: 'b',  43: 'e',  44: 'e',  45: 'c',  46: 'e',  47: 'c',  48: 'b',  49: 'b',  50: 'c'}, 'column_c': {0: 'b',  1: 'd',  2: 'b',  3: 'b',  4: 'd',  5: 'c',  6: 'b',  7: 'a',  8: 'a',  9: 'a',  10: 'a',  11: 'b',  12: 'd',  13: 'c',  14: 'b',  15: 'a',  16: 'a',  17: 'a',  18: 'b',  19: 'c',  20: 'a',  21: 'a',  22: 'b',  23: 'd',  24: 'd',  25: 'c',  26: 'd',  27: 'c',  28: 'c',  29: 'e',  30: 'd',  31: 'c',  32: 'd',  33: 'c',  34: 'b',  35: 'b',  36: 'd',  37: 'd',  38: 'd',  39: 'b',  40: 'c',  41: 'e',  42: 'e',  43: 'b',  44: 'b',  45: 'd',  46: 'd',  47: 'c',  48: 'e',  49: 'd',  50: 'b'}, 'column_d': {0: 'b',  1: 'c',  2: 'd',  3: 'd',  4: 'b',  5: 'b',  6: 'd',  7: 'd',  8: 'd',  9: 'b',  10: 'd',  11: 'c',  12: 'b',  13: 'a',  14: 'c',  15: 'c',  16: 'd',  17: 'c',  18: 'd',  19: 'a',  20: 'd',  21: 'b',  22: 'd',  23: 'b',  24: 'd',  25: 'e',  26: 'c',  27: 'c',  28: 'c',  29: 'd',  30: 'c',  31: 'e',  32: 'd',  33: 'd',  34: 'd',  35: 'b',  36: 'c',  37: 'e',  38: 'b',  39: 'e',  40: 'b',  41: 'c',  42: 'b',  43: 'e',  44: 'b',  45: 'c',  46: 'd',  47: 'c',  48: 'c',  49: 'b',  50: 'd'}, 'target': {0: 1,  1: 1,  2: 1,  3: 1,  4: 1,  5: 1,  6: 1,  7: 1,  8: 1,  9: 1,  10: 1,  11: 1,  12: 1,  13: 1,  14: 1,  15: 1,  16: 1,  17: 1,  18: 1,  19: 1,  20: 1,  21: 1,  22: 1,  23: 1,  24: 1,  25: 0,  26: 0,  27: 0,  28: 0,  29: 0,  30: 0,  31: 0,  32: 0,  33: 0,  34: 0,  35: 0,  36: 0,  37: 0,  38: 0,  39: 0,  40: 0,  41: 0,  42: 0,  43: 0,  44: 0,  45: 0,  46: 0,  47: 0,  48: 0,  49: 0,  50: 0}}`

What I am trying to accomplish is to select a subsample of this dataframe of an arbitrary length or percentage, but in doing so, I want to maintain (as closely as possible) the frequency distributions of each value for each class.

For example, if I want to simply subsample the dataframe, I can use [`.sample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) method

`smaller_df = df.sample(n=100)` or `smaller_df = df.sample(frac=0.1)`

However, it could be the case that the distributions of each value in each column in each class are lost. I need to preserve these value densities while downsampling my dataset size.

I can see these frequency densities with:

```
for col in df.columns:
    print(df.groupby(['target'])[col].value_counts(normalize=True))
```

That output looks like:

```
      target        column_a
0       e           0.384615
        c           0.269231
        d           0.230769
        b           0.115385
1       a           0.360000
        b           0.320000
        c           0.240000
        d           0.080000
```

I have seen [this post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63738389/pandas-sampling-from-a-dataframe-according-to-a-target-distribution) which seemingly answers that for a *single* distribution, but not multiple.

Ideally, how can I downsample my dataframe to maintain each columns frequency distribution with *less* samples? My actual dataset is `(8370994, 731)`

Comment: `s = df.groupby('target').sample(frac=0.5)` should reserve the relative distribution with some (small) errors. You can go as far as `df.groupby(list(df.columns)).sample(frac=0.1)`.

Comment: The relative distribution of all columns (i.e., `column_a`, `column_b`, `column_c`, `column_d`? Or just `target`?

Comment: I believe your suggestion @QuangHoang gets us mostly there, but this does so independent of the distributions _for each class_, and does it for the dataframe as a whole

Comment: If you groupby `target`, then the distribution of `target` is guaranteed to be the same. Whereas, the *relative distribution* `p(column_a | target)` **should** be the same since `sample` is random and independent from the original distribution. This holds for `p(column_a=a, column_b=b | target)` as well. If you group by `list(df.columns)`, then all the distributions are guaranteed to be the same. **Note** *the same* always means *with some small error*.